# How to check the number of places returned by google places api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Hi i have developed an android app using google places api.

Now i want to count the number of places returned by the google places api so as to assign a unique id to each of them using which i access a database.

I searched google but am unable to find how to calculate the number of places returned by google places api.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but each place returned by the Places API contains a unique ID in the ID field. Could you not use this as a database reference?

Comment: Hmmm in the database i have assigned a unique id for each of them and i want to use them...

Comment: What are you storing in your database? For performance reasons you are allowed to cache the `id`, `reference` and `name`. You are then required to issue a details request with the `reference` each time you want to access the place information.

Comment: I have a list of items got in a grocery store which have their own id using php to connect to mysql db...

Comment: Im still confused with what you are trying to achieve. Please update your question with some more details, including some code.

Comment: I want to display a list of products available in each store displayed using google places api when i click on them either using my own db or using the stores website.

Comment: Please store the Place `reference` and `id` in your database with your list of products obtaining in that Place. You can the issue a Place Details request with the reference for the place to see where those items were obtained.